# Inconsistent onTextChanged() behaviour

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I wrote the code below to figure out how onTextChanged() method works:

```
override fun onTextChanged(string: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged triggered.")
                Log.d(TAG, "string = $string")
                Log.d(TAG, "start = $start")
                Log.d(TAG, "before = $before")
                Log.d(TAG, "count = $count")
                Log.d(TAG, "____________________________________________________________")
```

Here's what I noticed: when I'm typing letters only, the count is pretty straightforward:

```
onTextChanged triggered.
string = a
start = 0
before = 0
count = 1
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aa
start = 0
before = 1
count = 2
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaa
start = 0
before = 2
count = 3
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaa
start = 0
before = 3
count = 4
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa
start = 0
before = 4
count = 5
____________________________________________________________
```

Now if I add 3 (or more) digits and then keep on typing letters, this is what happens:

```
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa2
start = 0
before = 5
count = 6
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa22
start = 0
before = 6
count = 7
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222
start = 0
before = 7     
count = 8
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222
start = 0
before = **8**      <---- This is when it gets funny
count = **8**
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222a
start = 8
before = 0
count = 1
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222aa
start = 9
before = 0
count = 1
 ____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222aaa
start = 10
before = 0
count = 1
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222aaaa
start = 11
before = 0
count = 1
____________________________________________________________
onTextChanged triggered.
string = aaaaa222aaaaa
start = 12
before = 0
count = 1
____________________________________________________________
```

To me it seems like inputing 3 digits somehow changes the TextWatcher's behaivior making it treat everything that comes after as a Char rather than a CharSequence.

Is there an explanation to this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have an explanation why it happens with 3 digits, I found out that there is no guarantee when offesets will be invalidated at all. Check this  [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int))

"You are not told where the change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other changes and **invalidated the offsets**. But if you need to know here, you can use `Spannable#setSpan` in `onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int)` to mark your place and then look up from here where the span ended up."

One possible implemetation of `TextWatcher` would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765509/466577).
That way you will have the proper begin and end indexes.